# Can we produce energy by red-shifting light

Tags: energy, visible-light, gravitational-redshift, redshift

The answer on my question [Does light accelerate as it nears a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241020/does-light-accelerate-as-it-nears-a-black-hole#241020)  leads me to think that light 'gains' the gravitational energy by shifting to a frequency with a higher energy (blue). Is this thought correct?

And is there any method of forcing light to red-shift?

Is this the same principal where low temperature combustion is red... Higher temperature blue (stars)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reflect it on a moving mirror... which will cost you exactly the amount of energy that you will gain from the blueshift. Sorry... no free lunch.

Comment: If by using a moving mirror to redshift light, in what form would the energy released after the shift?

Comment: The energy gets transferred to (or from) the kinetic energy of the mirror. A real application of this could be solar sails for spacecraft.