# What happens if we exert more force on an object which would be travelling at near maximum light speed?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, mass-energy, faster-than-light

If we exert force on an object which would be travelling at near light speed, to an extent to make it move greater than speed of light in vacuum, what would happen? If object doesn't move faster than light, what happens to that excess force?

Is this experiment been done? What would happen if we exert force on light travelling at its maximum speed?

Comment: *"to an extent to make it move greater than velocity of light"* - I've voted to close your question for the reason that non-mainstream physics is considered off-topic here.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri is referring to the fact that **there is no amount of force** that can accelerate an object from below light speed to above light speed.  (According to Newtonian mechanics, you can of course accelerate objects past light speed, but according to relativity --- which appears to be the context of your question --- you can't.)

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Note that the OP says "which *would*" not "which *will*", and then he or she goes on to suggest that the object might not.   I think it's a mainstream physics question. You might have misinterpreted the intention of the question.

Comment: @garyp, noted and I don't think so.

Comment: Please [do not make your post look like a revision table](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/25301), instead just seamlessly integrate the new material into the post. There is an edit history button at the bottom of the post for those interested in seeing what changed.

Comment: FWIW, special relativity places no upper limit on acceleration, momentum, or kinetic energy.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question, and I'm baffled by the close votes. The OP just wants to understand the answer to a FAQ about special relativity. That doesn't mean it's not a question about mainstream physics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you apply a force (in the direction of motion) to an object with mass, moving close to the speed of light, the object will accelerate and its speed will become even closer to the speed of light. But no amount of force can make it reach, or exceed, the speed of light.

The reason that objects behave this way is that momentum is not $m\mathbf{v}$ as Newton thought; it is in fact $m\mathbf{v}/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ as Einstein realized. Applying a constant force will cause the momentum to increase indefinitely, but the momentum becomes arbitrarily large as the speed approaches $c$.

There is no way to exert force on light. It always travels (in vacuum) at the speed of light, and cannot be sped up or slowed down.

Why? Well, photons don’t have charge, so they don’t feel electromagnetic force; in fact they carry electromagnetic force. Nor do they feel the strong or weak nuclear forces. They do feel gravitational force, but it doesn’t make them move faster or slower. (In General Relativity, they just move on lightlike geodesics.) These four forces are all the fundamental forces, as far as we know.

There is plenty of experimental evidence for these facts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why is there no way to exert force on light?

Comment: From theory, it may be saying the impossibility, but practically what would stop us from exerting force on light?

Comment: Photons don’t have charge, so they don’t feel electromagnetic force; in fact they *carry* electromagnetic force. Nor do they feel the strong or weak nuclear forces. They do feel gravitational force, but it doesn’t make them move faster or slower. (In General Relativity, they just move on lightlike geodesics.) These four forces are all the fundamental forces, as far as we know.

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't gravity speed up light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98750/why-doesnt-gravity-speed-up-light)

Comment: Your previous comment seems to belong to answer for the completion of the answer.

Comment: I’ve incorporated the comment into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its speed would get *yet  closer* to that of light, albeit tending to *infinitesimally* so as the initial speed tends towards the speed of light; and the mass would increase without bound. It becomes simpler to think of it in terms of *putting energy into* the particle, rather than applying force to it. You could well say that as the body's motion exchanges the *Newtonian* regime (speed a small fraction of *c*) for the *ultrarelativistic* regime (rest mass energy *m₀c²* a small fraction of kinetic energy), increase in *speed* for a given small increase  in *momentum* (small fraction of *m₀c*) is *exchanged* for increase in *mass* for a given increase in *energy* (that doesn't have to be small relative to m₀c²). This phenomenon is *routinely* observed: for physicists working with particle accelerators, it's *as routine* a phenomenon as vehicles passing along the road is to a city dweller; and also it's why an elementary cyclotron has an upper bound on the energy to which it can accelerate *protons* of ~42MeV.

Comment: Modern treatments of special relativity generally avoid using relativistic mass. It can lead to incorrect results if you aren't *very* careful. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133376/why-is-there-a-controversy-on-whether-mass-increases-with-speed and the linked questions for details.

Comment: Do they! That's interesting. I'm abitt _oldschool_ ... about prettymuch _everything_! I'd be interested to see how it's reframed. One cute little recipe that I'm fond of is the one that has ... can't remember what they call it now ... _haste_, or something - _atanh(β)_.

Comment: You're thinking of rapidity, which is a convenient measure of speed in relativity because it does add linearly.

Comment: That's it yes! - _rapidity_. I do like that formulation & the linear adding of it. I'm going to _campaign_ now to have it renamed "haste". You joining me!?

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey Even Einstein disliked the idea of ”relativistic mass”. See the Wikipedia article “Mass in special relativity”. The preferred “reframing” is in terms of energy, momentum, and (invariant) mass. Energy is the temporal component of a Lorentz 4-vector. Momentum is the spatial component of that same 4-vector. Mass is the invariant “length” of that 4-vector, left unchanged by Lorentz transformations.

Comment: I _do_ appreciate these objections to the use of mass in this sense. I can see that under this reframing the _relativistic_ part of my answer would become a mere _tautology_: "... an accession of _energy_  would increase the _energy_"! It's not so much that it makes the answering of the question of this post particularly _difficult_ though ... but it does kind of make it look a bit more _dogmatic_: "an accession of momentum or of energy increase the momentum or energy (respectively) of the body without much increasing its speed, because in the

Comment: relativistic régime they _just don't have_ to (indeed _can't_) anymore"! The idea of relativistic mass has at least the _elegance_ of conveying that the energy or momentum somehow becomes embodied _in the body itself_ without having to be manifested as increase in _speed_.

Comment: Actually, I have written somewhat at the post at that link in _PM 2Ring_'s comment. Don't know whether you'll like it or not, as it _very_ slanted according to my _personal slant_ on the matter; but I think you will probably agree that it shows that I am not atall _oblivious_ to the objections to the concept of relativistic mass.