# The Sun bends planets' trajectory and speeds up it towards the perihelion; does it both actions with light?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, orbital-motion, frame-dragging

The Sun bends planet's trajectory and speeds up it towards the perihelion; does it both actions with light? If it speeds up light too, then does it mean that gravity is a consequence of a vortex that transports massive objects, as well as light vibrations, like a highway does to vehicles? I read an answer on PSE site about the vortex-like effects of a star to two identical masses, where these masses have different net velocities when moving at a same distance around that star, one in direction of the possible vortex and the other in counter direction of the vortex.

Comment: What do you mean by "does it both actions with light?"?

Comment: @ThePointer... first action-bend of trajectory...second action speed up the object......in the case of light there is the first action but is there the second action of acceleration of light?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't gravity speed up light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98750/)